# White space on left of page when viewing on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, whitespace

There is a problem with my CSS in that there is a blank white space on the right side of the page when viewing on an iPad. I've looked around and tried different fixes with no success.

www.web-dex.com/healthytweens

The container is 1000px which I know is cutting it close to iPad's minimum 1024px but it still shouldn't go beyond 1000px.

Comment: Would that _blank white space_ be about 24 pixels wide by any chance?

Comment: i had the same problem and found that i had another DOM element that was a bit wider.

Comment: No it seems to be a bit larger than 24px. It looks fine on http://ipadpeek.com/

Comment: I've just checked it in the iPad Simulator and a lot of your elements are too wide which is causing the white space. You'll need to reduce their size or make them more responsive.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. May I ask what simulator you used? It would be of great help to me.

Comment: The iPad/iPhone simulator is a part of the Apple Developer Kit, which is a gigantic download. It only works on Apple computers, though. It's very accurate, and is a great tool if you don't have one of those devices.